# php printing and updation in to db

Tags: php

I have few values existing in data base,i need to update them but,i am unable to do it.

> UPDATE Phone SET dcno='1' WHERE number='1' AND date='12/03/2009' AND dcnodate='11/05/2009' AND yourorderno='1' AND orderdate='23/06/2010' AND vendorcode='2222

Couldn't execute query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2222' at line 3

I also need to print 3db value in to one form,i m unable to do it.

Any help ii be appreciated.

http://dpaste.com/hold/185341/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing quote at the end:

```
vendorcode='2222
```

In the code the quote is missing at two places where `UPDATE` is being used:

```
....vendorcode='{$good_data['vendorcode']}'";
```

Comment: Nope,Still i m getting that error.Now,it is echoing that it has updated but it isnt reflecting in db.

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like you're missing the ' from the 2222.

try running that query in your database see what happens

Comment: Nope,Still i m getting that error.Now,it is echoing that it has updated but it isnt reflecting in db.

Comment: then my only thoughts would be the where clause in your statement is preventing it from working. Either that or you havent reloaded the table??

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ending quote for last parameter:

```
"... AND vendorcode='{$good_data['vendorcode']}'";
```

To prevent such errors in future you should use `mysqli_prepare` with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`. You'll find example on [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Nope,Still i m getting that error.Now,it is echoing that it has updated but it isnt reflecting in db.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be two solutions.

1) add vendorcode='2222';

2) remove vendorcode=2222;